# $p$-groups with nontrivial intersection of nonnormal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I study the following paper about finite $p$-groups,

Finite groups in which the non-normal subgroups have nontrivial intersection,
N. Blackburn, Journal  of  algebra,  3, 30-37 (1966).

In this paper the intersection
of all non-normal subgroups of $G$ is denoted by $R(G)$.
We say that a group $G$ is an $R$-group if $G$ is not a Dedekind group and $R(G)\neq 1$.

The main result of this paper is as follows,

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group. If $G$ is an $R$-group, then $p=2$ and one of the
following holds.\
(i) $G\cong Q_8\times C_4\times E$, where $E$ is elementary abelian.\
(ii) $G\cong Q_8\times Q_8\times E$, where $E$ is elementary abelian.\
(iii) $G$ is a $Q$-group, i.e. $G=\langle x,A\rangle$, where $A$ is an abelian subgroup which is not
elementary abelian, $x^2\in A$  has order $2$, and $a^x=a^{-1}$
for all $a\in A$. In this case  $R(G)=\langle x^2\rangle$. Also, if $A$ is cyclic then $G$ is a generalized quaternion group.
In particular, if the centre of $G$ is cyclic, then $G$ is a generalized quaternion group.

I have a question about the third type ($Q$-groups) of this classification.

Let $c(G)$ denotes the nilpotency class of the group $G$ and $\displaystyle\bar{G}=\frac{G}{R(G)}$.
Is it true that $c(G):=c(\bar{G})$?

Any commnt or answer will be appreciated!

Comment: Dear Professor Holt, is it possible to determine such $Q$-groups for which this property holds?

Comment: I think it holds in cases (i) and (ii), where $c(G) = c(\overline{G})=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. If $G$ is a generalized quaternion group then $c(\overline{G}) = c(G)-1$.